# Select Input TYPO3 v9 Symfony Command

Tags: php, symfony, command, typo3, typo3-9.x

I want to make a scheduler command in TYPO3 v9, the problem is, that I don't know and can't find how I can make a select input.

This is what I have:

```
/**
 * Basic configuration(s) for the command.
 */
protected function configure(): void
{
    $this->setName('WiRo Workflow')
        ->setDescription('Sendet eine E-Mail an den Redakteur, wenn Inhaltselemente länger als 6 Monate nicht bearbeitet wurden')
        ->addArgument('mailFrom', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'Absender-Adresse')
        ->addArgument('mailFromName', InputArgument::REQUIRED,'Absender-Name')
        ->addArgument('mailTo', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'Empfänger-Adresse (nur für Chefredakteure und Administratoren)')
        ->addOption(
            'colors',
            ['blue', 'red'],
            InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED | InputOption::VALUE_IS_ARRAY,
            'Which colors do you like?',
            ['blue', 'red']
        )
        ->addOption('optionTV', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'Benachrichtigung an: Themenverantwortlicher')
        ->addOption('optionAdmin', null, InputOption::VALUE_NONE, 'admin')
        ->addOption('optionAdminAct', null, InputOption::VALUE_NONE, 'Benachrichtigung an: Chefredakteur und Administratoren (Aktualisierung)')
        ->addArgument('mailTimeToCheck', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'Anzahl Monate der Seiten, die zu prüfen sind:')
        ->addArgument('urlMandant', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'URL des Mandanten')
        ->addArgument('pageContact', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'Themenverantwortliche beziehen aus:')
        ->addArgument('rootPageID', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'Root-Page')
        ->addArgument('excludePages', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'Auszuschließende Seiten (Komma separierte Liste)')
        ->addArgument('mailSignature', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'Mail-Signatur');
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Peter Kraume for editing my question, now it is definitely more understandable. #hobbyless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot put user choice questions on the command options..., instead you have to use a ask method of helper with ChoiceQuestion object to

- In your commande

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Question\ChoiceQuestion;

// ...
/**
 * Basic configuration(s) for the command.
 */
protected function configure(): void
{
    $this->setName('WiRo Workflow')
        ->setDescription('Sendet eine E-Mail an den Redakteur, wenn Inhaltselemente länger als 6 Monate nicht bearbeitet wurden')
        ->addArgument('mailFrom', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'Absender-Adresse')
        ->addArgument('mailFromName', InputArgument::REQUIRED,'Absender-Name')
        ->addArgument('mailTo', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'Empfänger-Adresse (nur für Chefredakteure und Administratoren)')
        ->addOption('optionTV', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'Benachrichtigung an: Themenverantwortlicher')
        ->addOption('optionAdmin', null, InputOption::VALUE_NONE, 'admin')
        ->addOption('optionAdminAct', null, InputOption::VALUE_NONE, 'Benachrichtigung an: Chefredakteur und Administratoren (Aktualisierung)')
        ->addArgument('mailTimeToCheck', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'Anzahl Monate der Seiten, die zu prüfen sind:')
        ->addArgument('urlMandant', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'URL des Mandanten')
        ->addArgument('pageContact', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'Themenverantwortliche beziehen aus:')
        ->addArgument('rootPageID', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'Root-Page')
        ->addArgument('excludePages', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'Auszuschließende Seiten (Komma separierte Liste)')
        ->addArgument('mailSignature', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'Mail-Signatur');
}

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
{
    //...

    $helper = $this->getHelper('question');
    $question = new ChoiceQuestion(
        'Which colors do you like?',
        ['blue', 'red'],
        0 // default is blue
    );

    $question->setErrorMessage('Color %s is invalid.');

    $color = $helper->ask($input, $output, $question);
    $output->writeln('You have just selected: ' . $color);

    // doSomething with $color


    return 0;
}
//...
```